# How can i use ArcGIS server 10 mapservices in OpenLayers2?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, map-service

I'm new in OpenLayers. I'd like to use mapservice of ArcGIS server 10 in open layers.I search and found examples of  using an ArcGIS Server 9.3 Rest API layer for OpenLayers. I found `OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest` instance but not ArcGIS 10 . How can I use ArcGIS server 10 services in Openlayers? I wrote the below code . I use ArcGIS server 10 and The REST is working right .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
<head>

    <title>My OpenLayers Map</title>
       <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        var map;

        function init() {

          map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element',{});
var arcgis = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest("MyName","http://xxxxxxx/ArcGIS/rest/services/test/MapServer",

          {layers: "show:0,1,2,3,4"});

                    map.addLayers([arcgis]);

                    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload='init();'>
<div id='map_element' style='width:1000px; height:500px;'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you try using the ArcGIS9.3 Layer? It should work for ArcGIS Server 10.x as well.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I use this code but it's not working.       var map;

        function init() {
            
          map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element',{});
var arcgis = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest("MyName",
                                   "http://.../ArcGIS/rest/services/silver_test/MapServer",
                                   
                                     {layers: "0,1,2,3"}
                                   );
                                   
     map.addLayers([arcgis]);
 
           }

Comment: Can you reference the service via WMS, new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS()?

Comment: @artwork21 yes . it works for arcgis service . thanks

Comment: i have encounterd the same problems using OpenLayers to add ArcGis Rest Mapserver,i tried three ways,but they don't render correctly,such as,when i dragging the map the vector didn't move with the baseMap,so,how did you solved this problem at last, any advices would be great,thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without Looking at your code, I can't say why you can't access your ArcGIS Server 10 layer. But I can access ArcGIS map service layers in my OpenLayers App in the following ways:

- When the map service is a tiled Mapservice in WebMercator, I can use the following code:

`layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ( "ESRI",                        "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}", {sphericalMercator: true} );`

- When I have a dynamic mapservice, I can use the following code:

`layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest( "ArcGIS Server Layer", "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/export",                     {layers: "show:0,2"});`

There are two working examples on the OpenLayers website:

1. [Basic ESRI Map Cache Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/xyz-esri.html)
2. [ArcGIS Server 9.3 Rest API Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/arcgis93rest.html)

Comment: I Wrote the code in the question. It's not working. is there an error in my code ?

Comment: @wetland Your code seems to be missing the `/export` in the url parameter of the Layer constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If you have switched on the WMS capability of the map service, then you can consume the service as a [WMS Layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html), using the `OpenLayers.Layer.WMS()` class.

Answer (score 0):

Now is year 2018, openlayers is version 5.x.x

for arcgis rest api map server url like below,

```
 var url = 'https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
      'Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer';
```

ArcGIS REST MapService as tiles. This source type supports Map and Image Services.

example:

[ArcGIS REST MapService as tiles](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/arcgis-tiled.html)

For feature server url like below:

```
var serviceUrl = 'https://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
      'Petroleum/KSFields/FeatureServer/';
```

example:

[ArcGIS REST Feature Service](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html)